# Getting the indexOf of an array using filter in the controller (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I'm trying to update the sections of stores in my user. To do this I think I need the indexOf the array. I can get it in the html, but am having a hard time doing it in the angular controller.

```
//controller
// How do I get indexOf $scope.global.user.store[?] here instead of in html?
$scope.$watch('radio.model', function() {
  $scope.filteredArray = filterFilter($scope.global.user.store, {});
}, true);
```

I can select a radio button and it'll tell me the indexOf the store in the Array

```
<!-- html -->
<div ng-repeat="entry in filteredArray | filter: {name:radio.model.name}">
  {{filteredArray.indexOf(entry)}}
</div>
```

I need to be able to say, for example, $scope.global.user.store[1].section = $scope.newSectionInput so I can $update. My friend told me there's another way to update an object inside an array using something called the dot rule, if that helps answer this question. How do I get the indexOf inside the js controller? Been working on this for 24+ hours, tried searching all over, can't find the answer to this question.

Update:

```
<li ng-repeat="store in global.user.store">
  <label ng-model="radio.model" btn-radio="store">
    {{store.name}}
  </label>
</li>
```

So the idea is it's a section in the store. So I look up the store object which has a name property and section property. And I want to update the store object with different sections.

Comment: You want to get index of what? Index of selected radio? In this case, u need just add ng-model to the radio input.

Comment: Thanks for your interest/response, Petr. I'm just trying to update an object inside user. So the radio is an ng-repeat of store in global.user.store. I'll edit my original question for you.

Comment: you will get index of each ng-repeat item in $index, for proper solution please host your code on fiddle.:)

Comment: This is the fiddle I have so far and the radio buttons won't stay red when I click them? http://jsfiddle.net/Squ34k3rZ/0zz1zLzL/2/

Comment: {{filteredArray.indexOf(entry)}} is the wrong approach. You need to use an angular filter for operations such as these